# How do I add object properties into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

Here's a fiddle. 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/GF9nj/1/
What I'm trying to figure out is why when I .push my object data into the randomAnswerArray it doesn't show up even in the testing <p>. It's about halfway down the JavaScript section.

Here is the code in question:

```
// incorrectAnswer1, incorrectAnswer2, incorrectAnswer3 are initialised elsewhere ...
randomAnswerArray = []; //resets the array to empty
randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.correctAnswer);
document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML=randomAnswerArray[0]; //TESTING doesn't work
randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectAnswer1);
randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectanswer2);
randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectanswer3);
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = randomAnswerArray.valueOf();
```

the valueOf() call displays only the 0 and 1 items from randomAnswerArray, but I'm pushing 2 & 3 as well.

---

Here is the full code of the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<p id='questionString'></p>
<p id='test1'></p>
<p id='test2'></p>
<p id='test3'></p>
<button onclick='generate()'>Click me to start!</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var questionList = [];
var randomAnswerArray = [];

// this is the question object constructor

function quizQuestion(question, correctAnswer, incorrectAnswer1, incorrectAnswer2, incorrectAnswer3) {
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.incorrectAnswer1 = incorrectAnswer1;
    this.incorrectAnswer2 = incorrectAnswer2;
    this.incorrectAnswer3 = incorrectAnswer3;
}

// this constructs a question

var hairColor = new quizQuestion("What color is my hair?", "black", "blue", "red", "purple");

// this adds the question to the questionList

questionList.push(hairColor);
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = questionList[0].correctAnswer; //TESTING object constructor works
function generate() {

    // this part picks a random question
    var randomQuestion = questionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length)];

    // this part puts the question in the questionString
    document.getElementById("questionString").innerHTML = randomQuestion.question;

    // this part puts the answers in the array

    // THIS IS WHAT WE ARE TESTING    VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    randomAnswerArray = []; //resets the array to empty
    randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.correctAnswer);
    document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML=randomAnswerArray[0]; //TESTING doesn't work
    randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectAnswer1);
    randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectanswer2);
    randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.incorrectanswer3);
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = randomAnswerArray.valueOf(); //TESTING doesn't work
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    // this part randomizes the array

    var currentIndex = randomAnswerArray.length;
    var temporaryValue;
    var randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = randomAnswerArray[currentIndex];
        randomAnswerArray[currentIndex] = randomAnswerArray[randomIndex];
        randomAnswerArray[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle has a script error `generate is not defined`.

Comment: how is it not defined? I'm pretty sure that I set up the function correctly, right?

Comment: James asks, James answers.

Comment: James* is right. To be able to test I need to add $('button').on('click', generate);

Comment: i have that in the html part just under the < p>'s it's set up according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp

Comment: @Me look at the console on the fiddle...

Comment: in chrome F12 - console "Uncaught ReferenceError: generate is not defined"

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GF9nj/6 take a look

Comment: velthune if you take a look at the valueOf() it doesn't show the [2][3] values of the array which is what I don't understand.

Comment: Code from fiddles should always be included in the question so that they'll be reproducible in the future if the fiddle is no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your push statements you misspell these

```
 incorrectAnswer2
 incorrectAnswer3
```

as

```
incorrectanswer2
incorrectanswer3
```

Comment: oh my god thank you so much this was driving me nuts. <3

Comment: as you can probably tell i'm new to this programming stuff but so far it seems like the big errors are always small stuff like this.

Comment: Feel free to "accept" this answer ;-) And yes, an awful lot of big errors are these kind of glitches - sadly though, sometimes you get something much nastier :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the function generate does not exist because JsFiddle adds the javascript code as function in the onLoad event. This make the generate function to be declared in a different private context.
I suggest to add the js code

```
window.generate = generate;
```

as the last last of your code. This way you will set the generate function in the global namespace. and your onClick event will know call it properly.
If you fix this, your script will run properly.

I also updated your fiddle for you: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GF9nj/9/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GF9nj/34/ check out the undefined spaces and the incomplete third paragraph

Answer (score 1):

So here's the issue. It's a JSFiddle thing. Set the no wrap in body under Framework and Extensions option. The way the javascript is being loaded, your function is not visible in the scope like you think it is. I can explain further in an edit if you'd like

JSFiddle wraps your JS in the document's onload event by default. So your function was not defined in the root scope as you thought, but in the scope of the document.onload function, and you couldn't reach it from within the body, because that is outside of that function. I changed the JsFiddle attribute 'wrap in' to 'no wrap (body)' and it worked.

You really shouldn't bind your functions with the onclick tag. A better solution would be to remove the onclick from the button, and replace it with an `id="button"`

Then at the bottom of your javascript, `document.getElementById('start').onclick=generate`

Comment: I suspected such behavior (:

Comment: I fixed what you said and here's what I have http://fiddle.jshell.net/GF9nj/14/ the problem now is that my [2][3] are undefined  but my [0][1] seem to be fine.

Comment: randomAnswerArray = []; //resets the array to empty
    randomAnswerArray.push(randomQuestion.correctAnswer);
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML=randomAnswerArray[2]; How in the world can randomAnswerArray[2] have a value if you set it to an empty array and then only push one element? only randomAnswerArray[0] has an element at this point. you need to populate the array before you set the values in your test tags